# Scraper with POST request doesn't bring any results

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

Creating a scraper using post request, when i run it, i get nothing. Can't understand what i'm doing wrong. Using chrome developer tools when I see the form data query it seemed that if i pasted the total string in the console then it looked odd that is why i tried to concise it. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.golf.co.nz/PlayGolf/ClubDirectory.aspx"

def grab_data(address):
    payload={"ctl00$MainContent$cbRegion":"All Regions","ctl00$MainContent$cbHoleOpt":"Any number of Holes"}
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.post(address, data=payload, headers = headers)
    tree=html.fromstring(response.text)
    names=tree.xpath("//td[@class='align-left']//h2/text()")
    for name in names:
        print(name)

grab_data(url)
```

Elements for formdata:

```
<div id="MainContent_pnlForm" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'MainContent_btnSearch')">


                                <div id="MainContent_pnlFilters">

                                        <div>
                                            <select name="ctl00$MainContent$cbRegion" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$cbRegion\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_cbRegion" class="ddl-filter">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">All Regions</option>
            <option value="1">Aorangi Region</option>
            <option value="2">Auckland Region</option>
            <option value="3">Bay of Plenty Region</option>
            <option value="5">Canterbury Region</option>
            <option value="6">Hawkes Bay Region</option>
            <option value="7">Manawatu/Wanganui Region</option>
            <option value="10">North Harbour Region</option>
            <option value="11">Northland Region</option>
            <option value="12">Otago Region</option>
            <option value="13">Poverty Bay/E. Coast Region</option>
            <option value="14">Southland Region</option>
            <option value="15">Taranaki Region</option>
            <option value="9">Tasman Region</option>
            <option value="16">Waikato Region</option>
            <option value="17">Wellington Region</option>

        </select> 

                                            <select name="ctl00$MainContent$cbHoleOpt" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$cbHoleOpt\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_cbHoleOpt" class="ddl-filter">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Any number of Holes</option>
            <option value="9">9 Holes</option>
            <option value="18">18 Holes</option>
            <option value="27">27 Holes</option>
            <option value="36">36 Holes</option>

        </select>


                                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbSearch" type="text" value="SEARCH" size="10" id="tbSearch">

                                            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch" value="GO" id="MainContent_btnSearch" class="module-button-cta submit-filter">
                                         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this is what I get after parsing and am not able to proceed from here.
    
    >>> tree=html.fromstring(response.content)
    >>> tree
    <Element html at 0x26371e0>
    >>> tree.text
    '\r\n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The formdata parameter needs to be set as exactly what chrome developer tools displays.I tried to post my answer here but couldn't because with fully satisfied formdata crosses 75000 characters whereas body allows 30000.